# & in if else condition in matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement, logical-operators

I want to write a function in Matlab for
[image]

This is what I wrote.

```
function f=hamacher(x,y)
for i=1:5
    if x==0.00 & y==0.00
        f=0;
    else 
        f=(x.*y)./(x+y-(x.*y));
    end
end
end
```

If I let

```
>> p=[0 0.5 1 0 0.75];
>> q=[0 0.2 0 0 0.8];
>> hamacher(p,q)

ans =

       NaN    0.1667         0       NaN    0.6316
```

This results `NaN` and not `0` because of `0/0`. I want to handle this issue by
`if x==0.00 & y==0.00
            f=0;`

Why doesn't this `if` statement handle this?
Can someone please tell me how I can correct this.

Comment: To understand the behaviour, I recommend to read the documentation for if carefully. Your expression `x==0.00 & y==0.00` is only true if all elements are nonzero. This would mean your input contains only zero elements.

Comment: Also, your `for` loop seems to not add anything, you're just evaluating the same expression 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function f=hamacher(x,y)
f = zeros(numel(x),1);
for ii=1:numel(x)
    if x(ii)==0 && y(ii)==0
        f(ii,1)=0;
    else 
        f(ii,1)=(x(ii)*y(ii))/(x(ii)+y(ii)-(x(ii)*y(ii)));
    end
end
end
>> p=[0 0.5 1 0 0.75];
>> q=[0 0.2 0 0 0.8];
>> hamacher(p,q)
ans = 

         0
    0.1667
         0
         0
    0.6316
```

I'm quite sure this is what you wanted. I just made sure everything works element wise and not vectorised.

Comment: Thank You. It  works correctly. Can you please explain what does `f = zeros(numel(x),1);` do?

Comment: It initialises `f` to have one column and `numel(x)` rows, i.e. as much rows as there are elements in `x`. Initialising a variables is always a good idea with respect to both computational time and memory requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Since your function is [vectorized](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html), use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) to distinguish the two cases element-wise:

```
ind = x==0 & y==0;
f(ind) = 0;
f(~ind) = x(~ind).*y(~ind)./(x(~ind)+y(~ind)-(x(~ind).*y(~ind)));
```